# 'permission' pipe could not be found?

Tags: angular, aspnetboilerplate

Following [step by step dev](https://docs.aspnetzero.com/documents/zero/latest/Developing-Step-By-Step-Angular#authorization-for-phone-book) I am trying to *Hide Unauthorized Button* .

this is the code of the button ,in phoneBook.component.html :

```
<button *ngIf="'Pages.Tenant.PhoneBook.CreatePerson' | permission" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="createPersonModal.show()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> {{l("CreateNewPerson" | localize)}}</button>
```

when i run the project , i get that error in console :

```
ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
   The pipe 'permission' could not be found ("
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
              .......
```

how could i fix , this problem ?

Comment: Have you created the pipe before in your code?

Comment: Did you declare the pipe in your `*.module.ts`?

Comment: no i didn't create the pipe neither declared it in *.module.ts . i just followed the step by step dev

Comment: See [Angular - Pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) It's noted somewhere on that page: `You must include your pipe in the declarations array of the AppModule.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe definition is provided in v6.7.0 of the ASP.NET Zero base solution.

If you are using an older version, you can  view the corresponding version of the docs:
https://docs.aspnetzero.com/documents/zero/v6.6.0/Developing-Step-By-Step-Angular#hide-unauthorized-button

This is the diff (truncated) from [aspnetzero/documents@bccbc7a](https://github.com/aspnetzero/documents/commit/bccbc7a253c1c36e8c39ad3fb8f21872e447e9a7):

```
- *ngIf="isGranted('Pages.Tenant.PhoneBook.CreatePerson')"
+ *ngIf="'Pages.Tenant.PhoneBook.CreatePerson' | permission"
```

Comment: thank you  the project has been given to me by the chef , how to find it's version ?

Comment: It's in **AppVersionHelper.cs** if it hasn't been replaced.

Answer (score 2):

[Custom pipes need to be created and imported into module.](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)
A pipe can be used like this:

```
<button *ngIf="(Pages?.Tenant?.PhoneBook?.CreatePerson' | permission).length === 0" 
    class="btn btn></button>
```

Then your pipe should look like this:

```
@Pipe({name: 'permission'})
export class PermissionPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number, exponent: string): number {
    ...
    return ...;
  }
}
```

And the declaration in module:

```
import { LabTestService } from './lab-test/lab-test.service';
import { PermissionPipe } from './...';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        PermissionPipe 
    ],
    imports: [
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule        
    ],
    ...
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: you mean that i need to create the pipe ? this wasn't mentionned in the documentation

Comment: @A.HADDAD yeah, you can't  use pipe without creating a pipe. please, read this documentation  https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Comment: @A.HADDAD If it is built-in pipe, then yes, you can use such a pipe. However, custom pipes need to be created and imported into module. I've added this into my reply.

Answer (score 0):

In the codes of your link, they use "permission" as a data.

So I think they do a mistake. They don't want to have a pipe here but a boolean data from the back.

So it might be `<div *ngIf="... || permission">`

(Their github link is dead so no possible way to have a clean code)

Comment: no i don't think it's a mistake, cause the button should disappear if a user haven't the permission which isn't the case with your code

Comment: I can't say. But if they define permission in the component, then it's `<div *ngIf="... || permission">`  (or && or !permission, I don't know)